# PHP Classes and global variables

Tags: php, oop, class, global-variables

I recently begun to use classes. I've been using procedural programming for quite a while so it has been a bit challenging.

My question.

If I have a class like this:

```
class Example {

   public $name;
   public $whatever;
   public $yearAdded

   public function __construct($name, $whatever=NULL, $dateAdded)
   {

   some trival code here;

   }


}
```

How can I make `$yearAdded` use a global variable I set up somewhere else in another script?

FOR EXAMPLE:

```
global $currentYear = date('Y');
```

Would I have to do this way

```
new example($name, $whatever, $currentTime);
```

or is there a way to specify within the class to always use `$currentYear` for `$yearAdded`.

Answer (score 2):

The `global` keyword doesn't work the way you think it does.  It does not make a variable have global scope.  All it does is specify to the function that you call it in that you want to use the variable in the outer scope.

For example:

```
$a="test";

function something() {
    global $a;
    echo $a;  //Outputs: test
}
```

If you want to make a variable global so that it can be accessed from within a class, you need to use the `$GLOBALS` superglobal.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

This is not considered to be the best OOP way of doing things, but will get the job done.

Comment: Do you think that it is best in your experience to use these superglobals for something like a current timestamp or is it best to keep that kind of information specific to a class. I know the example I provided is a bit abstract.

Comment: what would be consider best OOP way of doing so?

Comment: @Hugo, The best thing to do would be to build classes so that they are generic in a way where it makes sense to pass them anything they need to function in a constructor.  Then, for each function, pass anything in addition as parameters to them.  The only time I break this rule is for things like a database connection, or configuration options.  Purists would say even those should be passed as well, and they are right.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a builtin `time()` function, so why do you need a home-grown global variable in your constructor?

If you think carefully about how you are using globals, you'll find out that there are usually better ways of accessing the same info -- e.g. system environment variables, configuration files, etc.

Comment: the reasoning is that almost everything that happens in the system gets a time added to the DB. Example: Job gets posted to the system, in the db I have a table with a field called dateAdded which contains 2011-10-01 12:22:00 (NOW). But the database is on a different time zone than the user for example, so I have to account for time zones. So I set a global variable for that user which has their current time and date. Not sure if that's the optimal way of doing it... so I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: The `time()` function yields unix time that is universal (UTC). If you look at `Date()`, then calling `year` with the `o` format flag gives you a UTC year that is also time-zone independent. See [link]http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.

Comment: @rsj, You won't be able to guarantee that the clocks are in sync for the DB server and the web server.  Even if they're all using NTP, errors can happen.

Comment: Sure, and how will you keep the global variables in synch on the different servers scattered around the world? Perhaps you can re-invent NTP :P

Comment: sorry to get snarky. But coordination problems among multiple web servers accessing the same db doesn't really have anything to do with the use of global variables in PHP -- unless you are suggesting some network protocol for synchronizing each server's copy of the global variable, At which point, use a central time server seems like a good way to go.